# htaccess- to hide subdirectory slug only from the post

Tags: htaccess, directory

I have two wordpress installed, one is a travel blog in the root directory as www.mysite.com. And I have installed another in subdirectory named "fitness" under my root directory and the domain name looks like www.mysite.com/fitness. Here I want www.mysite.com/fitness to be accessible as a home page for fitness section. At the same time, I want the slug "fitness" to be removed in my post URL. Say for www.mysite.com/fitness/post1, here I want www.mystyle.com/post1.

For these changes to happen I have modified my htaccess in my root to this:
[image]

But now the posts in my main URL i.e., www.mysite.com/post2 is inaccessible and getting 404 error.
Also in future, I want to create one more subdirectory under the root and the domain will be like www.mysite.com/lifestyle. And I want the same method to this folder also, as used for subdirectory "fitness".
Please provide me the solution, and what changes need to be done in my htaccess file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right when using separate directory you cannot have root directory for all 3 web sites Apache is not that smart but If you have some router function or front controller than it is another case but still you have to use separate directory for separate website.